# How can I tell the type of a local variable in IntelliJ's debugger?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

```
// from Selikoff and Boyarsky Java 17 certification
public class Ex0 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        short x = 10;
        short y = 3;
        var z = x * y;
    }
}
```

I want to tell what the type of the var is but I do not see it in the debugger.

Even the types of x and y are not shown.

[image: ide]

Comment: just do not use `var`!

Comment: `z` is an `int`. (something no wider than an int) * (something no wider than an int) is an int. So `byte*byte=int`, `byte*short=int`, `short*short=int` etc.

Comment: If you're using `var` then you don't care what it is.  The compiler will figure it out.

Comment: @stdunbar no, I am trying to tell what the type of var is. It is a java certification question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can right click on IntelliJ's debugger tool window, select "Customize Data Views", and enable "Declared type".

[image: show declared type]